# calculating net force in python

Tags: python, tuples

EDIT!!:

I forgot to add this, it is present in my code:

```
from math import sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan2, radians, degrees, sqrt
```

I am calculating net force, and I have run into a roadblock. My feedback on this problem seems to be that I need to:

"Convert to radians prior to manipulating them using the cos / sin in the for loop."

I have been working on this for hours and I have to say my brain is a little fried. Can someone help me?

This should be printing out:

(87.0, 54.4)

Right now all I am getting is an error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'horiztonal_total' referenced before assignment

Here is my code:

```
def find_net_force(forces):
    horizontal_total = 0
    vertical_total = 0
    for i in forces:
        horizontal = i[0] * cos(i[1])
        vertical = i[0] * sin(i[1])
        horiztonal_total += horizontal
        vertical_total += vertical
        
    total_magnitude = sqrt(horizontal_total ** 2 +  vertical_total ** 2)
    horiztonal_total = radians(horizontal_total)
    vertical_total = radians(vertical_total)
    total_angle = atan2(vertical_total, horizontal_total)
    total_angle = degrees(total_angle)
    total_magnitude = round(total_magnitude, 1)
    total_angle = round(total_angle, 1)
    force = (total_magnitude, total_angle)
    return force

forces = [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
print(find_net_force(forces))
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because of a typo. Look at the name `horiztonal_total` carefully. - next problem...you need to import the math functions you're using via: `from math import sin, cos, sqrt, radians, atan2, degrees`.  Once I apply those two fixes to your code, I get AN answer, but I guess it isn't the right one.  I get: `(76.0, 2.2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code. Syntactically, there are two:

`horiztonal_total` is a typo.  Should be `horizontal_total` in all cases.

You need to import the math functions:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, radians, atan2, degrees
```

Logically, the problem is when you're applying `radians()`.  You're doing it in the wrong places, and not doing it in places you should.  Here's the version of your code that gives the right answer:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, radians, atan2, degrees

def find_net_force(forces):
    horizontal_total = 0
    vertical_total = 0
    for i in forces:
        horizontal = i[0] * cos(radians(i[1]))
        vertical = i[0] * sin(radians(i[1]))
        horizontal_total += horizontal
        vertical_total += vertical

    total_magnitude = sqrt(horizontal_total ** 2 + vertical_total ** 2)
    total_angle = atan2(vertical_total, horizontal_total)
    total_angle = degrees(total_angle)
    total_magnitude = round(total_magnitude, 1)
    total_angle = round(total_angle, 1)
    force = (total_magnitude, total_angle)
    return force

forces = [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
print(find_net_force(forces))
```

Result

```
(87.0, 54.4)
```

Remember that `radians()` turns degrees into radians.  Also know that all math operations accept and return angles in radians.  Since your input values are in degrees, it makes sense that you would wrap references to them in `radians()` before passing them to `sin()` or `cos()`, as in `cos(radians(i[1]))`.  That gives you a unit force.  That is, a force in a specific direction assuming the total force was `1`.  To get the total force from some magnitude other than `1`, you multiply the magnitude by the return value from sin/cos, which you were already doing.

`atan2` does, in effect, the opposite of calling `sin()` and `cos()`.  It turns a pair of magnitudes into an angle.  The result is in radians. Since you want your result in degrees to match your input values, you call `degrees` on the result.

Good work.  You were really close on this!  Happy coding!

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, the cos and sin goes outside the radians. Thank you, I am not as educated as I would like to be on the math aspect. Think I need to brush up on my understanding.

Comment: I just added some more comments that will, I hope, be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Using @CryptoFool's comment:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, radians, atan2, degrees

def find_net_force(forces):
    horizontal_total = 0
    vertical_total = 0
    for i in forces:
        horizontal = i[0] * cos(i[1])
        vertical = i[0] * sin(i[1])
        horizontal_total += horizontal
        vertical_total += vertical
        
    total_magnitude = sqrt(horizontal_total ** 2 +  vertical_total ** 2)
    horizontal_total = radians(horizontal_total)
    vertical_total = radians(vertical_total)
    total_angle = atan2(vertical_total, horizontal_total)
    total_angle = degrees(total_angle)
    total_magnitude = round(total_magnitude, 1)
    total_angle = round(total_angle, 1)
    force = (total_magnitude, total_angle)
    return force

forces = [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
# Convert to radians here 
forces = [(force, radians(angle)) for (force, angle) in forces]
print(find_net_force(forces))
# (87.0, 54.4)
```

You did a great job, the only changes I made were to correct the typo from `horiztonal_total` to `horizontal_total` in two separate places, imported the relevant math functions and then converted from degrees to radians because in `math`, those functions take arguments as radians and your  angles are given in degrees.

Answer (score -1):

your input is in degrees and sin and cos take radians. So you need to write:

```
horizontal = i[0] * cos( radians(i[1]) )
vertical = i[0] * sin( radians(i[1]) )
```

These two lines don't make sense:

```
horiztonal_total = radians(horizontal_total)
vertical_total = radians(vertical_total)
```

All in all

```
def find_net_force(forces):
    horizontal_total = 0
    vertical_total = 0
    for i in forces:
        horizontal = i[0] * cos( radians(i[1]) )
        vertical = i[0] * sin( radians(i[1]) )
        horizontal_total += horizontal
        vertical_total += vertical
        
    total_magnitude = sqrt(horizontal_total ** 2 + vertical_total ** 2)
    #horiztonal_total = radians(horizontal_total)
    #vertical_total = radians(vertical_total)
    total_angle = atan2(vertical_total, horizontal_total)
    total_angle = degrees(total_angle)
    total_magnitude = round(total_magnitude, 1)
    total_angle = round(total_angle, 1)
    force = (total_magnitude, total_angle)
    return force

forces = [(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
print(find_net_force(forces))
```

outputs

```
(87.0, 54.4)
```